# jQuery flexigrid search value not cleared

Tags: jquery, jsp, flexigrid

I am using the jQuery flexigrid plugin.  I have an issue though - when I use the search:

[image: flexigrid search 1]

it, as expected, includes the search value in the POST:

```
page    1
qtype   vendorName
query   VC1
rp      10
sortname    vendorName
sortorder   asc
```

However, after I close the search:

[image: flexigrid search 2]

the POST **still** contains the search value!  Granted, the user can clear the value themselves but that IMO is not intuitively obvious.

I'd like the POST to be this once the search is closed:

```
page    1
qtype   vendorName
query       
rp      10
sortname    vendorName
sortorder   asc
```

So, can anyone tell me how to clear the "query" value when the flexigrid search is closed?

Comment: You're asking a few questions about the same library in quick succession here.  You might try to check with the flexigrid plugin's author for help, these questions seem to be pretty specifically tailored to that library rather than general purpose programming questions.

Comment: I had two questions, this one and one more.  There is no support for flexigrid, so asking this community.  If you don't know, that's fine - maybe someone else will.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this?  There are a lot of flexigrid questions on SO, so I hope someone can help...